# How do I get a CSS transition to apply to styles dynamically generated by React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a button component that makes use of a theme provided by a context:

Button.js

```
() => {
  const theme = useContext(themeContext); // { primaryColor: "blue" }
  return <button className="MyButton" styles={{ backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor }}>Hello</button>
}
```

Button.styles.scss

```
.MyButton {
  background-color: purple
  transition: background-color 0.1s
  &:hover {
    background-color: green
  }
}
```

Since the background color is now being set by React, the transition effect no longer works. Is there a way to get this to work without, for example, rewriting everything in `JSS` (given that all the app's styling is done in `scss`).

Comment: `Since the background color is now being set by React, the transition effect no longer works` the transition works perfectly, it's the Specificity in CSS that is in your way. Inline-styles outweigh your hover-style

Comment: Transition isn't working? Or is the background color which is always primary? Your inline styles probably are overriding `className`

Comment: @Thomas why would setting an inline style 'outweigh' the hover style? As in, why does it matter how the original `background-color` gets set? I would think that the `::hover` property would apply even if `background-color` gets set from somewhere else.

Comment: The cascade and specifity are at the very core of how CSS works. In comparison to that is ':hover' an advanced topic. You need to learn the basics. Check out [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and the linked [CSS Specificity Wars](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)

Comment: @Thomas I'm quite aware of how the cascade works. I'm just confused because the only thing that should be changing in the sample code I have in my post is the `background-color: purple` should change to `background-color: blue`. The transition should remain, however it gets removed when the JSX styles are merged with the scss styles. Does that make sense?

Comment: `button:hover` has a specifity of `11`, your inline-style has a specifity of `1000`. Which one wins? There is no transition, because the background-color does not change. The inline-style outweights everything you define in your style-sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the React theme isn't setting transition and hover rules? If it is, then the only way to override those is to set the styles inline. Perhaps add onto the theme object (or a clone of it) before assigning in the styles attr, or somehow overlay the theme nearer to its source.